# Unknown flag status should lead to 404 page

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page, error-message, 404-not-found

One's flag summary statistics is divided into *groups*:

1. Post flags
2. Spam flags
3. Rude/offensive flags
4. Comment flags

Within these, each group is subdivided by *status*:

1. Pending flags
2. Helpful flags
3. Declined flags
4. Disputed flags
5. Aged away flags
6. Retracted flags

These flags can be viewed by visiting the URL

```
http://*site*/users/flag-summary/*userid*?group=X[&status=Y]
```

Specifying the `&status=Y` is optional. However, if you do specify `&status=Y` where `Y` > 6, you land on the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page. There seems to be no need "[d]etailed information about this error" to be "... automatically [...] recorded and [someone be] notified."

My suggestion would be to send the user to the 404 page instead, as that information is not available.

Comment: Or better yet ignore the `status` query and just take you to `group=X`

Comment: FYI: you _can_, actually, access the flag summary page without `group=X`. There's also `group=0` (which it defaults to) which leads to All Flags.